# Add text above image in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiedgeinsets

So I have UIButton's all over various VC's and Scenes on my game. Some with images others just plain text. So I want to combine both. I know I can do both but the button is then in the background. Is there anyway I can make sure that the text is above said image and the whole thing is clickable?

Everything i'm doing is via the storyboard and not programmatically but i'm fine with doing programmatic. I'm looking at the API as we speak and it seems that I'll have to deal with edges? Never done that before so, just need some guidance :/

The guide I looked at before on stackoverflow was from 5-7 years ago and applies which is fine but setting the edges isn't as self explanatory as it might seem :/
Here's what I have:

```
dosplayas.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(((dosplayas.frame.size.height)*(-(2))), 0, 0, 0)
```

I also tried positive two and I tried it as the first of 4 parameters because the first one is the top according to the API

Answer (score 1):

When setting image, just set background image rather than regular image. it'll allow text on top
Then change text to attributed rather than plain
Then..here's a screenshot:

-click the 3 dots
-change the lining to like 7-20 depending on the size of your text

[image]